# FTP in NetBeans 6.1

Tags: netbeans, ftp

Is there an FTP browser hiding away in NetBeans 6.1? The help manual doesn't even suggest FTP exists.

All I've been able to find so far is a tree viewer in the Services panel (no edit controls) and the ability to upload projects, folders and specific files from the Projects/Files views. Is there anywhere to delete or rename or will I have to keep switching back to my browser?

I can see from the previews that there's a nice FTP controller in 6.5 but I'm not desperate enough to completely convert to a beta (yet).

Comment: Have you taken a look at [remotefs](http://remotefs.netbeans.org/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like something was recently added to netbeans for php...

http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/ftp_support_added

don't know if you can make use of that...

Answer (score 1):

The remotefs addin works for 6.5:
[remotefs](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=13195)

[image]
<sub>(source: [netbeans.org](http://plugins.netbeans.org/nbpluginportal/files/images/1220982228486_remotefs.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can try the Plugin FTP Site Deployer. This is free and open source plugin for Netbeans, it's add a contextual menu with the voice "upload to FTP". Is still in development but it is working:

You can find some other information here:
http://www.askweb.it/wordpress/?p=136

And download source and nmb from sourceforge
https://sourceforge.net/projects/ftpsitedeployer/